Heron's triangle made up of square numbers
I'm Japanese.
Is there a triangle whose sides are all square numbers and whose area is an integer? I would appreciate it if you could give me a concrete example if you have one.
[PS] I finally found a triangle that satisfies those conditions!
a=86^2,b=127^2,c=142^2, the area is 55059062.

Supppose that there was such a triangle. Call the sides of the triangle $a^2, b^2$ and $c^2$. What does Pythagoras tell you about the relationship of $a, b$ and $c$? Now what does Fermat's theorem tell you?

I'm not sure I understand this "converse" remark, since I'm aiming at a proof by contradiction, but maybe I just need another cup of tea.

I have to say that I really like the problem as stated -- the "integer area" is a very nice red herring. Perhaps, using that, there's some parity argument that doesn't need the big guns of Fermat.

@John Hughes I think we were both of us fooled by the presence of squares on sides, but it doesn't mean that Pythagoras is to be used !

@JohnHughes Can you elaborate further? The only way I can make sense of your hint, is if we additionally assume that this is a right triangle.

Y'know...I read "right triangle" rather than "triangle" when I looked at the problem. And that is, indeed, the only situation in which my misguided hint makes sense. (Jean Marie was hinting at this, I think, but I was too dull-witted to understand.)

Not an answer, but perhaps a start on an answer
Suppose for a moment that there is such a triangle. Then there is a smallest such triangle (where the "size" of a triangle will be, say, the length of its shortest edge).
NB I'm assuming here that you want none of $a,b,c$ to be zero; if you allow that, it's easy: a 1-1-0 triangle works, for instance.
Let's pick a triangle with sides $a,b,c$ with $a \le b \le c$ (by re-labelling as needed), and with $a$ as small as possible. We'll also assume that $a,b,c > 0$, by negation if necessary.
Observation: $(a^2 + b^2 + c^2) = (a^2 - b^2 + c^2) + 2b^2$,  so the parenthesized expressions on the left and right have the same parity (i.e., both are even or both are odd). The same goes for $(-a^2 + b^2 + c^2)$ and $(a^2 + b^2 - c^2)$.
We also know (by assuming that this is a solution to the problem, and using Heron's formula) that the area
$$
H = \sqrt{\frac{(a^2 + b^2 + c^2)(-a^2 + b^2 + c^2)(a^2 - b^2 + c^2)(a^2 + b^2 - c^2)}{2}}
$$
is an integer. That means that the numerator of the fraction under the radical must be divisible by $2$, i.e., must be even.
All four factors of that numerator have the same parity, by the observation above. If all four were odd, then their product would be odd, a contradiction. So all four are even.
Unfortunately, all I can derive from this is that $2a^2, 2b^2,$ and $2c^2$ are all even, which is hardly a surprise. But maybe it's a start. If I could prove that $a, b$ and $c$ were all even, then we could perhaps divide each by 2, and get a smaller triangle, leading to a contradiction. But I can't figure it out and I'm dozing at my keyboard, so I leave this here as a possible starting direction.

If we consider the parity of $a,b,c$, there are only two cases: "all even", or "one even, two odd". The other combinations yield odd factors in the numerator under the radical.
